# Removing the rows if there are more than or equal to 3 NaN (null)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am removing the rows of my dataframe if any one of the row has greater than or equal 3 empty values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\GANGA\Desktop\titanicmodupd.csv')
new_data = df.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any',thresh=3) 
print(new_data)
```

Input:

[image]

Actual output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
new_data = df.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any',thresh=3)
```

with

```
new_data = df.dropna(axis = 0,thresh=3)
```

When you are providing how as 'any’ it means If any NA values are present, drop that row or column. so it removes all columns with na and your "`thresh=3`" is ignored.

Hope this helps..

Comment: it worked when I given thresh=3 but when I give 2 it is not working as expected.

Comment: Is it a different issue that is occuring now?.

Comment: it is the same one.but instead 3,I am trying with 2.

Comment: When thresh =2 it means. Keep only the rows with at least 2 non-NA values. I guess your problem is due to confusion as thresh demotes the number of non-NA values and not the number of NA values